# Правильное использование указателя с переменными, значение которых вводится через консоль

Tags: c++, указатели

Я знаю что на ru.stackoverflow уже есть похожие вопросы, но в них указатель используется с переменными, которым уже присвоено числовое значение, и там все понятно.

Меня интересует, как использовать указатели, если переменной не присвоено изначальное значение, а оно вводится через консоль (на примере нижеуказанного кода).

**Код С++:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Worker

{
    private:
        string name;
        string place_of_work;
        int age;
        int *p = age;


    public:

        void inputinfo() {
            cout << "Input age: ";
            cin >> age;
            cout << "Input work: ";
            cin >> place_of_work;
            cout << "Input name: ";
            cin >> name;


        }
        void outputinfo() {

            cout << "Age: " << p << endl;
            cout << "Work: " << place_of_work << endl;
            cout << "Name: " << name << endl;


        }
};


int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    Worker n1;

    n1.inputinfo();

    n1.outputinfo();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где здесь указатель? Где вы собираетесь использовать указатель?

Comment: Хочу сделать указатель на age(поправил немного код).

Comment: Этот код вообще не соберется даже, поправьте на `int *p = &age`, ну и в выводе тоже исправьте. И не очень понятно, в чем вопрос.

Comment: Указатель указывает на **переменную**, а не на значение. Поэтому при работе с указателем нет разницы, присвоено значение переменной или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот демонстрационная программа, показывающая, как использовать указатели на члены класса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Worker
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string place_of_work;
        int age;
        std::string Worker::*ps;
        int Worker::*pi;

    public:

        void inputinfo() {
            std::cout << "Input age: ";
            pi = &Worker::age;
            std::cin >> this->*pi;
            ps = &Worker::place_of_work;
            std::cout << "Input work: ";
            std::cin >> this->*ps;
            std::cout << "Input name: ";
            ps = &Worker::name;
            std::cin >> this->*ps;
        }

        void outputinfo() {

            std::cout << "Agr: " << age << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Work: " << place_of_work << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Worker n1;

    n1.inputinfo();

    n1.outputinfo();
}
```

Если в качестве ввода использовать данные значения

```
18 Peter Junior
```

то вывод на консоль будет выглядеть как

```
Input age: 18
Input work: Peter
Input name: Junior
Agr: 18
Work: Peter
Name: Junior
```